# Projectiles/Bullets direction Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am following a tutorial on a [simple cocos2d game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial).

however on that tutorial the bullets that the user fires is only on one direction

what can i do to make it fire on all directions not just one sided?

here is the code of the direction.

```
int offX = location.x - projectile.position.x;
int offY = location.y - projectile.position.y;

[self addChild:projectile];

int realX = winSize.width + (projectile.contentSize.width/2);
float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
int realY = (realX *ratio) + projectile.position.y;
CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

int offRealX = realX - projectile.position.x;
int offRealY = realY - projectile.position.y;
float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
float velocity = 480/1;
float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

[projectile runAction:[Sequence actions:[MoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
                       [CallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)], nil]];
```

all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am also following Ray's blog to learn cocos2d. Even I would like to know the answer.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the projectile at the location of your character, you just need to figure out the direction before calculating the end point.

After adding the projectile:

```
[self addChild:projectile];
```

Add a scalar float:

```
float scalarX = 1.0f;
```

And make it negative if the touch is left of the character:

```
if (offX < 0.0f) scalar = -1.0f;
```

Then just multiply the `realX` by this scalar to make it point the correct way

```
int realX = scalar * (winSize.width + (projectile.contentSize.width/2));
```

Comment: can you answer this link also... i had the same problem with the monsters : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797777/firing-bullets-monster-position-in-cocos2dsprites    
thanks

Comment: I've had a quick go but I couldn't really get a full grasp on what you guys wanted explained. Let me know if I've misunderstood