# Monsters/Enemies on Platforms(like on Doodlejump)Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new here so i hope you can help me.

I am following a tutorial on making simple cocos2d game

[Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial)

I implemented it on another game a jumping one like doodle jump.

in the said tutorial the monsters/targets are moving freely coming from the right to the left side of the screen. when i implement it on my app the monsters are like flying from left to right. What if i want the monsters to stand on the platforms just like the one on doodle jump? what particular things will i do?

**PS:i tried some other things on google but none works**

Here is the code of the monsters/targets:

```
- (void)initPlatforms {
//  NSLog(@"initPlatforms");

    currentPlatformTag = kPlatformsStartTag;
    while(currentPlatformTag < kPlatformsStartTag + kNumPlatforms) {
        [self initPlatform];
        currentPlatformTag++;
    }

    [self resetPlatforms];
}

- (void)initPlatform {

    CGRect rect;
    switch(random()%2) {
        case 0: rect = CGRectMake(608,64,102,36); break;
        case 1: rect = CGRectMake(608,128,90,32); break;
    }

    AtlasSpriteManager *spriteManager = (AtlasSpriteManager*)[self getChildByTag:kSpriteManager];
    AtlasSprite *platform = [AtlasSprite spriteWithRect:rect spriteManager:spriteManager];
    [spriteManager addChild:platform z:3 tag:currentPlatformTag];
}


-(void)addTarget {

    Sprite *target = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"komodo.png"];

    target.position = ccp(300,200);

    [self addChild:target];



    CGSize winSize = [[Director sharedDirector]winSize];
    int minX = target.contentSize.height/2;
    int maxX = winSize.height -target.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) +minX;

    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    id actionMove = [MoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width,actualX)];
    id actionMoveDone = [CallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
    [target runAction:[Sequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone,nil]];
    target.tag = 1;
    [_targets addObject:target];


}
```

Thanks to those who will help... you are so nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question unfortunately, which makes it difficult to answer in any definitive terms. If you are hoping to create actual platforms that can be bounced on (in a doodle jump manner) you are going to need to implement collision detection between the Monsters and the Platform ccNodes. There are numerous tutorials online for cocos2d collision detection, both simple implementation and the more advanced box 2d/chipmunk based solutions.

If you are looking to clone doodle jump fairly closely, there is an open source version of a clone available on github  [here](https://github.com/haqu/tweejump) - though I've not actually looked at the code.

Finally, if you mean that you simply want to restrict the movement of the monsters to a particular area of the screen (so they don't keep running off the edge) you just need to position the target to an area on the screen and alter the`ccAction` so that the `ccMoveTo` uses the left most point of the 'platform' as the furthest point left it can move to and the right most point as the furthest right. (I'll confess I've not played Doodle Jump so have no idea what the enemies actually do).

If the enemies run back and forth across the platform you should look into using [ccRepeatForever](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_repeat_forever.html) on your movement sequence and have two destination positions in the `CCSequence` : one that moves the monster to the left of the platform, the other to move it to the right.

**Additional Info**

Ok, I see what you are trying to do. This should get you started:

**Platforms** are created in `initPlatforms`. This calls `initPlatform` a number of times. This grabs an image from the `AtlasSprite` for the platform, creates a `ccSprite` for each platform and assigns it a unique tag.

Then, in `- (void)step:(ccTime)dt` it loops through all the platforms and moves them to their correct location based on how far the bird has moved:

```
for(t; t < kPlatformsStartTag + kNumPlatforms; t++) {
        AtlasSprite *platform = (AtlasSprite*)[spriteManager getChildByTag:t];
//etc...
```

So, the bit you are waiting for:

If you want to add a monster to these platforms, you will have to follow a similar pattern. To get started try something like this (You will want to have a cleaner design than this though but it should put you on the right track)

in `initPlatform` add the following to the end of the function

```
// add a monster sprite
AtlasSprite *monster = [AtlasSprite spriteWithRect:CGRectMake(608,128,64,64) spriteManager:spriteManager];
[spriteManager addChild:monster z:3 tag:currentPlatformTag + 1000];
```

(I've just grabbed an image from the existing Atlas. You could replace the above with your actual 'Monster' sprite object.  Notice I add 1000 to the`currentPlatformTag`. This is just for testing; you should have a `monsterTag` implementation eventually.

So now every platform has a 'monster' (Again, you will only want to target random platforms)
so we need to update the positions for the monsters.

In `- (void)step:(ccTime)dt` directly after you get the current platform

```
AtlasSprite *platform = (AtlasSprite*)[spriteManager getChildByTag:t];
```

You now also need to get the current monster (remembering to use the updated tag value we created for 'monsters':

```
AtlasSprite *monster = (AtlasSprite*)[spriteManager getChildByTag:t + 1000];
```

Then, a few lines below where we reposition the platform we will need to reposition the monster

```
platform.position = pos;
// We update the monster and set it a 32 pixels above the platform:
monster.position = ccp(pos.x, pos.y + 32);
```

So now each platform has a monster on it whose y position moves with the the platforms :-)
Hope this helps

Comment: thats is exactly the app that i am working on the tweejump app.
here is the situation: i have put on the monsters.. what i want is them to be on the top of a platform and respawn randomly i dont think i have to use box2d and chipmunk because in tweejump the bonus is there at the top of the platform.so what i want is the monster to be like the bonuses standing on one platform waiting to be hit thats all sir. thank you

Comment: please help me sir..... i just need to put the monsters on a random platform and spawn them randomly.

Comment: what if my sprite is not included in the atlassprite manager how can i call it? i tried this but i used the bird image on the atlassprite manager it worked the birds are on the top of platforms. however they are not randomly respawning i mean every platform have a bird on top of it.... im sorry sir if im disturbing you too much thanks for understanding

Comment: @TeT You can get whichever sprite you want from outside the AtlasManager provided you haven't added it to the AtlasManager. When you create it, add it to the current layer ([self addChild:monsterSprite tag:currentPlatformTag + 1000]) and access it from the same node (AtlasSprite *monster = (CCSprite*)[self  getChildByTag:t + 1000]; )

Comment: @davbryn - Thank you it worked but how can i make it respawn randomly?
because i have my sprite all over the platforms 1 per platform. which if i made a target and hit will cause mutation crash

Comment: You just need to add your target's sprite to the platforms you want to add it to. I don't know if your target is a subclass of CCSprite or if it just includes a CCSprite, but either way it should be a CCNode (which you can position). So create a Target object and add that to self, then fetch it the same way you do with the sprite currently. To have it appear on random platforms try using arc4random() % n.  so only add an enemy if ((arc4random() % 2) == 0) would put an enemy on a platform 50% of the time

Comment: Thank you so much davbryn... i put arcrandom()%20 and it worked .

Comment: sir it is working now but im still having troubles like whenever i call [_targets addObject:target] on the step:(ccTime)dt it is calling the (update:) method everytime i start the game there is this one image at the lower left of the screen thats why whenever i fire a bullet at other monster is has this `'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x276fe0> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

and also it is laggy when the monsters appear